# Unable to download from github or google - through Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, android, eclipse, github

I am getting the following error when I click on "Spring Template Project" in Eclipse Juno

```
Error while downloading or parsing descriptors file 'https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-templates/master/si-sts-templates/builds/descriptor.xml':

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error while retrieving https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-templates/master/si-sts-templates/builds/descriptor.xml
```

Here is the log:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 1000 2013-04-25
>   08:39:20.295 !MESSAGE No repository found at
>   http://geronimo.apache.org/devtools/. !SESSION 2013-04-25 08:42:08.969
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200 java.version=1.7.0_21
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
>   -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.proxyHost=XXXXXXXXX -Dhttp.proxyUser=XXXXXXXXXXXX -Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXXXXXXXXXXX -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1 -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
>   Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
>   -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.proxyHost=XXXXXXXXXX -Dhttp.proxyUser=XXXXXXXXXXXX -Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXXXXXXXXXXX -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1 -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2013-04-25 08:42:18.304 !MESSAGE
>   Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of
>   native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level Git settings which
>   might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git
>   installation directory. The most important of these settings is
>   core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true
>   in this system level configuration. The Git installation location can
>   be configured on the Team > Git > Configuration preference page's
>   'System Settings' tab. This warning can be switched off on the Team >
>   Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core 4 0 2013-04-25
>   08:42:19.654 !MESSAGE Project facet grails.app has not been defined.
>   It is used in plugin com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.core.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2013-04-25 08:42:23.523 !MESSAGE NLS
>   unused message: CacheManager_CannotLoadNonUrlLocation in:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.messages

Sooo, my problem is: I cannot download from github and I also get the following, from google (for android):

> Unable to read repository at
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException

I'm thinking that the issue is related but...not sure.  I have adjusted the eclipse.ini file to include the proxy settings (i'm at work - the setting have been replaced, in the log, as XXXXXXXXXX).
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

URLs schemes are HTTPS, and your proxy settings are HTTP only.

You should try to set the HTTPS settings as well :

```
 -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=XXXXXXXXXX -Dhttps.proxyUser=XXXXXXXXXXXX -Dhttps.proxyPassword=XXXXXXXXXXXX -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

Also, you should probably use the preferences menu (Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections) to configure this.